# new, () and [] operators all at one instruction

Tags: c++, new-operator

Why can't I use the `new` operator like this:

```
char* p;

p = new char('a')[3];

delete[] p;
```

Compiler says:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '['
error C3409: empty attribute block is not allowed
error C2143: syntax error : missing ']' before 'constant'
```

Comment: Why would you want to? It just makes for messy code.

Comment: You can: `std::string p (3, 'a');`

Comment: @chris: No you can't. OP clearly gets a compile error.

Comment: @trinithis Eh? Why couldn't you use a `std::string`?

Comment: `char *` aint even `std::string` for one. Im just being pendantic

Comment: @trinithis, It still accomplishes the same result, and is just as scalable. If you really want the `char *`, you can get it when you're done with the string.

Comment: @trinithis: The moral of the point that chris is making is that "if you're using array-new, you're probably doing it wrong", period. C++ has better, safer, and more elegant and flexible idioms.

Comment: While true, I'm leaning more toward: "Just because you can't do it one specific way doesn't mean it's impossible to get the same result in the end." Of course both of those tie nicely together when the way that does work *is* better, safer, more elegant, and more flexible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11, you can initialize a dynamically allocated aggregate through the new [uniform initialization](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c19081/C-2011-Uniform-Initialization.htm):

```
p = new char[3] {'a', 'a', 'a'};
```

In C++98, you cannot specify an initializer list for dynamically-allocated aggregates.
All you can do is to first allocate the array, then fill it with a value:

```
p = new char[3];
std::fill(p, p + 3, 'a');
```

Comment: Perhaps we should add that the OP is getting an array of 3 chars, which he asked for, but it isn't a proper C string. The next question might be why `printf("%s", p)` isn't working.

Answer (score 5):

In C++11, you can say:

```
char * p = new char[3] { 'a', 'a', 'a' };
```

Pre-11 there was no way to initialize dynamic arrays other than to zero (or default). In that case, you could use `std::fill`:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::fill(p, p + 3, 'a');
```

Comment: Exactly the same answer, and obviously we didn't copy each other. Funny!

Comment: @akappa, I don't blame you. I was just thinking of `fill` myself.

Comment: @KerrekSB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595331/new-and-operators-all-at-one-instruction-c#comment15346194_11595331

Comment: @rubenvb, I don't think it's worth a downvote imo, but both of these guys are welcome to use my comment in their answers and expand on it any way they want. These more address the specific issue at hand, but past that is where the comment fits in.

Comment: @rubenvb: you are missing out the fact that brace initialization could only be used for **automatic** aggregate types, not with **dynamically allocated** aggregate types.

Comment: And, BTW, the fact that we have fancy structures like `std::vector` and `std::array` does not mean that plain, old-fashioned arrays are so useless it is dangerous to even explain what a brace-initializer is. There are cases when what you really want is an array. For example, I wrote a data compression algorithm, which needed to perform some copies using unaligned copies. To do that, I needed to do some brutal reinterpret-casts on the bare-metal arrays, something I couldn't do with fancy abstractions.

Comment: @akappa, True, I see the value in giving the answer that works directly. It's just almost always the case that an abstraction *would* be better.

Comment: @chris: of course: using the new facilities leads to code which is more readable, less error-prone and sometimes even faster. The point is what is the best answer to a question: just address what the OP is asking or just giving a more open-stretched answer, with design suggestions and stuff like that. This is highly subjective, so I assume everybody answer the way they like :)

Comment: @akappa, Yeah, I like more of a "Here's how you do it. Here's how you should probably do it." type of answer. The OP (or someone else who stumbles upon the question) might not know about the alternative, and even if the OP requires a raw array, others who come might not.